# Assign color if the column name is = to an array value

Tags: d3.js

I'm making a multiline chart and now I'm defining color like this

```
color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["rgba(255,255,255,0.90)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.20)","rgba(255,255,255,0.70)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.40)", "rgba(255,255,255,0.50)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.60)", "rgba(255,255,255,0.30)", "rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"]);
```

to assign color to line I use this code:

```
var tracciato = svg.selectAll(".line-group")
    .data(column)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return i +" line-group"; });

tracciato.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name)})
```

I ned override this color assignment if the column name value is equal to something...
- I have a csv with column name that are italian politician name
- I have an array defining the color of each politician
- I need to merge this data and if the column name is = to a politician name in the array I want to use this color instead of the color(d.name)
I wrote this code but it doesn't work...

```
var colore= [{  nome: 'renzi',col: '#ff0000'},{nome: 'berlusconi',col: '#0000ff'}]   

tracciato.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { 
    //if color array exist 
    if(colore != undefined){
        col_nome=d.name; //name of the column in the csv
        //I want to iterate through the array 
        for (var a = 0; a <= colore.length - 1; a++) {
          //and check if the col_name is = to array[a].nome
          if (col_nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(colore[a].nome) >= 0) {
              return colore[a].col;//if yes, use the color defined in the arry
            }
          else{return color(d.name);};//if not, use the standard color
        };


      }
      //if color array doesn't exist use standard color
      else{return color(d.name);}
    })
```

The issue is that the for is not performed but is lunched only one time and so the checking is made only for colore[0].nome
do you have any advice on how can I do to make the "for" works?

Thanks
Daniele
p.s.
sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code will work if you remove:

```
else{return color(d.name);};//if not, use the standard color
```

so the loop won't return early if the name doesn't match the `colore[0].nome`

Just for fun though, I rewrote your function in slightly more idiomatic d3:

```
.style("stroke", function(d) { 
  index = colore.map(function(d){ return d.nome; }).indexOf(d.name.toLowerCase());
  return (index == -1) ? color(d.name) : colore[index].col; })
```

Comment: wow the code you rewrite is super short... I just have to understand it :-)

Comment: Could you explain me how it works? This code prevent the checking if the "colore" array doesn't exist?

Comment: Yeah, I would set var colore = [] if it wasn't going to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop runs only once because you are returning from it regardless of the outcome of the comparison. The function you want looks like this.

```
if(colore != undefined){
    col_nome=d.name;
    for (var a = 0; a <= colore.length - 1; a++) {
      if (col_nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(colore[a].nome) >= 0) {
          return colore[a].col;
      }
    }
    return color(d.name);
 }
 else{ return color(d.name); }
```